# Convert json array with values only to csv using jq

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, jq

I have a below JSON and I need to convert it to a CSV. The problem I'm having is that those values have no key.

Ideally I would like CSV to look like this, I just don't know how to do it using jq.

CSV

```
year;points;surname;name;point1;points2;points3;city;district;url
2020;54;Smith;John;;;London;Waterloo;URL
2015;380;Helen;Smith;;;New York;Manhattan;URL
```

JSON

```
{
  "draw": 0,
  "total": "44",
  "filtered": "8",
  "data": [
    [
      "2020",
      "54",
      "Smith ",
      "John",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "London",
      "Waterloo",
      "URL"
    ],
    [
      "2015",
      "380",
      "Helen ",
      "Smith",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "New York",
      "Manhattan",
      "URL"
    ]
  ],
  "District": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample, .data[] is a stream of flat arrays, so to produce the CSV rows for the data, you could:

```
.data[] | @csv
```

Comment: that produce: jq: error (at <stdin>:32): array (["2020","54...) is not valid in a csv row. I can write Python and bash scripts but jq is something of a mystery...

Comment: As the preamble states, it is .data[] that produces flat arrays.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The question mentions CSV but the sample output shows semicolon-separated values, so here's a def that is like jq's built-in for tab-separated values but produces SSV, being careful to "escape" pre-existing semicolons in particular:

```
def ssv:
  map(if type == "string" then gsub(";"; "\\;") else . end)
  | @tsv
  | gsub("\t"; ";") ;
```

For example, with the -r command-line option:

```
["a;b", "c\td", "e\nf"] | ssv
```

produces:

```
a\\;b;c\td;e\nf
```

### Inverse operation

To recover the SSV values:

```
def ssv_to_values:
  # (?<!subexp)        negative look-behind
  splits("(?<!\\\\);")
  | gsub("\\\\\\\\;"; ";")
  | gsub("\\\\n"; "\n")
  | gsub("\\\\r"; "\r")
  | gsub("\\\\t"; "\t")
  | gsub("\\\\0"; "\u0000")
  | gsub("\\\\\\\\"; "\\");
```

E.g. using the -r command-line option:

```
["a;b", "c\td", "e\nf", "g\\h"] | ssv | [ssv_to_values][]
```

produces:

```
a;b
c   d
e
f
g\h
```

(That's a tab on the second line in the block above.)

Comment: Well, I did include semicolon-separated values but can be anything as long as I can later import this to Excel. I was thinking getting this into csv would be easiest.

Comment: CSV, TSV, SSV, PSV -- they all have their quirks.  TSV is by far the best-defined and in my experience also the most portable, but your mmv.